# How to mediate between one program written in nano editor and one in python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am controlling an LED matrix connected to Raspberry Pi using a code written in nano editor. And i am controlling a camera using opencv in windows. i want to synchronize both the programs. is there any way to do that?

Comment: you need to mention more about the type of language you have used write each bit of software, versions and product names are required if you want people to help

Comment: i have used python in as the language in raspberry pi.  Also, i have used python in open cv too. Opencv 2.4.11

Comment: we would need to a better idea of how the code works and what you want to do with it , to know how they would combine

Comment: What i actually want to do is write a python script in windows, where in between i can do ssh to connect to my raspberry pi and execute some file stored in its memory and then come back to my python script. How to start with this?

Comment: the easiest way to do ssh in python is to use shell out with subprocess and run ssh , a more portable solution is to use paramiko.